# How to publish container through web browser?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kubernetes, deployment, containers

I am trying to learn kubernetes. I can deploy containers.
How can we publish/show container through web browser?

> I think we can create nodePort through service.

How can we do this?
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: If you mean to say expose to the internet, than typically with a service of `type: LoadBalancer` and/or an ingress controller such as nginx-ingress.

Comment: If you are just learning then its better to start from node-port service and then eventually learn the best way to do this ie using ingress.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below manifest to deploy a sample nginx application in Kubernetes(using a LoadBlancer IP type). I have used Minikube so the way of accessing the application would be different. This is one way of accessing the application there are other ways 1.Using Nodeport 2. Using Ingress

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  namespace: dev
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "350m"
```

**Service.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
   app: nginx
```

Once these two files are created apply them using the below command

```
kubectl apply -f nginx.yml,nginx-service.yml
```

**Accessing the application on K8s provided by cloud providers**

If you are using kubernetes provided by some cloud provider then you will need to access the application from the `LoadBalancer IP`. This could be found by using the below command(I have deployed the application on dev namespace):

```
kubectl get svc -n dev
```

This should list a service called `nginx-service` and there will be an External IP for this service you have to access the application using that External IP.

**Accessing application on Minikube**

In Minikube if you want to access the application use the below command:

```
minikube service nginx-service --url
```

[image: Nginx pod's output]

To understand more about services refer : [Types of service in Kubernetes](https://linuxhint.com/different-kubernetes-services/)

Answer (score 0):

Define service type as NodePort. This makes the service accessible on a static port on each Node in the cluster. This means that the service can handle requests that originate from outside the cluster.

sample is given below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
  labels:
    run: my-nginx
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31704
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: https
    nodePort: 32453
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    run: my-nginx
```

You can also define service type as LoadBalancer if you are hosting your apps in Cloud.  The service becomes accessible externally through a cloud provider's load balancer functionality. GCP, AWS, Azure, and OpenStack offer this functionality. The cloud provider will create a load balancer, which then automatically routes requests to your Kubernetes Service.